# PowerShell script fails when called from Python, but can when run via PowerShell

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, office365

I have an issue, where a simple PowerShell script, when called from Python, fails to find the module `MSOnline`, but when running the PowerShell script from CMD/PS it runs as expected.

When the PowerShell script is run on it's own, it works perfect, and I feel as the Python script is working fine as it is pulling in the errors formatted from PowerShell as I want the format to be, but as it can't find the module, I am just at a loss.

**Python script that calls the Powershell script and pulls the output.**

```python
import subprocess, sys

def powershell(cmd):
    out = []
    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", cmd], stdout=sys.stdout)
    line = p.communicate()
    out.append(line)
    for line in out:
        print(line)

powershell(r"Path to Powershell script")
```

**PowerShell script that pulls users from Office 365 Online**

```bsh
Import-Module MSOnline
$username = "username"
$password = cat C:\Users\user\Documents\folder\securestring.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
Get-MsolUser
```

Can anyone shed some light on the reason that when the PowerShell script is called from Python, that it fails to import the `MSOnline` module, local computer's execution policy is set to "Unrestricted".

Comment: Please show the error.

Comment: Python 64bit or 32bit? Could be that it can't find a DLL.

Comment: Also, why are you running it via Python?

Comment: It was an error with 64bit Powershell and 32bit Python, and to answer your next question, it's basically going to be one big management system for Gmail/365/AD with a central database, i'm working on half and a collueage on another half, but more of learning process for myself.